# Thévenin resistance with simple dependent current source

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, thevenin

I want to find the Thévenin resistance from the terminals a-b. I've been trying out various methods that look correct to me but none of them seem to be the right answer: 4/9 kΩ.

First, according to `KCL` at node `A` I've considered that the current going through the right loop is `5I1` since the current going through the left loop is just `I1` and the dependent source provides `6I1`.

With this in mind I tried:

1. Transforming the dependent current source into a dependent voltage source, which gave me two resistors in series `R3 + R1`, which I added and then I transformed it back to a current dependent source. Now the Thévenin-Norton resistance should be the parallel resistors `R3+R1 // R2 = 2/3` which is wrong (not 4/9);
2. Then I tried calculating the Thévenin voltage at `a-b` and the Norton current by short-circuiting `a-b` and then apply `Rth = Vth/In`. `In = 5I1` and `Vth=5I1x1` and of course is not right either.

How can I calculate `Rth` in this setup? Also, I don't understand why the methods I've applied are wrong.

[image]

Comment: I think that one problem is there is not really a Thevenin voltage. Without an external source driving this circuit, nothing happens inside. It's like a transistor amplifier without a power supply.

Comment: Just apply a voltage U to A and B, calculate I1, and divide U by (-5R1) to get the current. I'm getting 800 ohms for the resistance without considering R2. Paralleling R2 gives 4/9k.

Comment: It is not Thevenin you apply here. Simply equivalence of two circuits (OP and a new one which is resistance only).

Comment: Ludicrous, the circuit is degenerate. If you have I1 passing through R3 then the voltage at node A must be I1*R3. But by KCL at node A, there must be 5*I1 flowing through R1+R2. But R1+R2=2*R3. So the voltage at node A must be 2*R3*5*I1 = 10*R3*I1. But we just said node A must be I1*R3 from the left side. How can node A be both I1*R3 and 10*I1*R3, unless I1 itself is 0. Therefore, I1=0 A and VA=0 V. Right?

Comment: Ludicrous - are we done here? Is the question answered to your satisfaction? If not then raise a comment under the most appropriate answer for getting feedback. Leaving the question open is not really a good thing; people get less interested in helping you when there is no clear reason for your inaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I want to find the Thévenin resistance from the terminals a-b.*

[image]

This is because if you apply 1 volt then \$I1\$ is 1 mA and, due to the current source, 6 mA is returned to the 1 volt giving a net load current of -5 mA hence, its equivalent resistance is -200 Ω.

Then if you simply did the analysis of R1 (1 kΩ) in series with -200 Ω all in parallel with R2 (1 kΩ) you get 444.444 Ω.

Answer (score 0):

Applying a voltage Uab to a and b, we can find the following relation:

R3⋅I1-5R1⋅I1 = Uab -> Rth = Uab/(-5I1) = 800 Ω.

This is not considering R2. Paralleling R2 with 0.8kΩ yields the answer 4/9kΩ.

Without assuming an external voltage all currents and voltages inside this circuit will be zero. That's why there's not really a Thevenin voltage or Norton current.